# ubuntu 11.10 installer starts again after shut down

Tags: 11.10, installation, shutdown

When I  install Ubuntu 11.10 in virtual box, everything works fine till this time. But when i shutdown the machine and boot it, installer again starts. Whatever changes made to the machine are also gone. The user name created is also not displayed anywhere.. Please help..

Answer (score 1):

remove the iso... look:

[image]

In my virtual machine with opensuse I leave the iso named openSUSE-12.1-DVD-x86_64.iso

You right clik to the disk image and unselect the iso.. this is where you can find it.

[image]

Is more easy if you use the config button and deattach this here:

[image]